# loading one html page inside other using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to load an html file ("hello_world.html") inside
another html page ("index.html") both files in the same location.
This is the code I wrote. But It is not loading anything.
both alerts are working ( which I intentionally gave to check whether
jquery is working or not .no other use with it)
what is the error in the code ? I dont want to use ajax.

```
</head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("document").ready(function() {
        alert("ya loaded");
        $('#container').load('hello_world.html');
    alert("finished");  
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Both alert will fire even if your `.load` doesn't work, because `.load` is asynchronous. And you are using AJAX.

Comment: What errors are occuring in your debugging console? Is the request being sent? what is the response?

Comment: If you don't want to use AJAX, you're going to need to use a server-side technology to include hello_world.html in the html being delivered to the client's browser.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using jQuery `1.3.2`? It's very outdated, use an up to date version if you can. May not help with your problem though.

Comment: If you are testing this on your local machine AJAX will not work due to the HTTP requests not having domain headers.

Comment: i am getting this error XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/Development/JQuery/jQuery%20Essential%20Training%20(RAKSHITHB)/Exercise%20Files/01_overview/hello_world.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. I am a begginer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your firebug or chrome development console to check out possible mistakes.

Edit:

When you use ajax, sometimes browser will not load it using `file:///` protocol.
You should be using a web server locally (such as xampp on windows or just apache),
and aproach your website in `http://` protocol.

That is very likely cause of your problem.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/helloworld.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. I am getting this error in console :( when i put an alert inside script, alert was working

Comment: Download from here: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html xampp and use it to serve your html files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19683/discussion-between-bhavin-bhaskaran-and-toninoj)

Answer (score 4):

Well, I have the following files in one directory:

helloworld.html

```
<p>hello!</p>
```

test.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("document").ready(function() {
            $('#container').load('helloworld.html');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Loading test.html in browser produces "hello!", so check if you jQuery is loaded properly.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/helloworld.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.                                          I am getting this error in console  :( when i put an alert inside script, alert was working

Comment: That's because you are not running it with a server....Try running it with a localhost server.. It will work. @BhavinBhaskaran

Answer (score -1):

the solution is so simple:

the ready function (line) you wrote is incorrectly
so you have to write document work without quotation mark
it will look like:

```
$(document).ready(function()({

});
```

Comment: That's not true! `$( document ).ready(..)` is equivalent with `$( 'document' ).ready(...)` in jQuery.