# How can I make the text from another webpage show?

Tags: php, html

I saw that a webpage was able to get the text off http://assetgame.roblox.com/game/GetAuthTicket

I am trying to do the same but it isn't working out. Any fixes?

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Nothing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Sorry, this webpage isn't completed yet.</p>
        <?php
            $domain = 'http://assetgame.roblox.com/game/GetAuthTicket';
            $handle = fopen($domain, 'r');
            $content = stream_get_contents($handle);
            fclose($handle);
            echo "<textarea rows='20' cols='80'>$content</textarea>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is already answered by Anton Egorov in his reply yo the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424477/loading-one-html-page-inside-other-using-jquery).

Comment: Without knowing any details I frankly doubt that something like `GetAuthTicket` can simply be requested without any form of session or context. Are you really sure that the result you get back is valid?

Comment: `but it isn't working out` What is the error? What's wrong?